# How to print Hive query after substitutions (to debug it)?

Tags: hive, hiveql

In order to avoid duplication or parameterize a query we can compose a query from many parts via substitution. However we might want to see the resulting query and check if it is correct. How to do it?

Consider a very minimal query:

```
hive> set hivevar:foo=bar;
hive> select "${foo}";
```

UPDATE:

Although `hive -v` prints the query to be executed the substitutions are not resolved:

It echoes the query but unfortunately without substitutions resolved:

```
$ hive -v
hive> set hivevar:foo=bar;
set hivevar:foo=bar
hive> set hivevar:query=select "${foo}";
set hivevar:query=select "${foo}"
hive> select "${foo}";
select "${foo}"
OK
bar
Time taken: 2.062 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Moreover I'd like a solution that works primarily in `beeline`, since `hive` CLI is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Since [variable substitution in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution) is based on plain strings we can:

- store a query in another variable:

  ```
  hive> set hivevar:foo=bar;
  hive> set hivevar:query=select "${foo}";
  ```
- then print it (note that all substitutions are resolved):

  ```
  hive> set query;
  query=select "bar"
  ```
- and execute it:

  ```
  hive> ${query};
  OK
  bar
  Time taken: 0.131 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same frustration when I had my sql in a file, and was running it with

```
hive -f
```

This didn't completely solve my problem, but adding

```
set;
```

before my query, allowed me to see how the ${hiveconf:variable} was being resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You could launch the hive command line with `hive -v` and it will echo back the SQL it is about to execute.

Comment: It echoes the query but unfortunately without substitutions resolved.